# Tesseract training - text2image returning Segmentation Fault every time on Ubuntu

Tags: ocr, tesseract, text2image

I'm trying to train a new language by following the [oficial turorial](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#generate-training-images-and-box-files/) but I just cannot perform the steps on *"Generate Training Images and Box Files/Prepare a text file"*. I've created my text file but every single time I run the command `text2image --text=training_text.txt --outputbase=eng.TimesNewRomanBold.exp0 --font='Times New Roman Bold' --fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts` the result is `Could not find font named Times New Roman Bold. Pango suggested font FreeSerif Bold
Please correct --font arg.:Error:Assert failed:in file text2image.cpp, line 437
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
.

This happens in the given example (I've used the one they used in the turorial) and on every single font I choose that exists in the list shown by running `text2image --text=training_text.txt --outputbase=eng --fonts_dir=/usr/share/fonts  --find_fonts --min_coverage=1.0 --render_per_font=false`
.

Can someone help me with this? I cannot go further with the tutorial because of this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours searching about this problem, I found out that what happens is that the **font** used in the command is not recognized by the OS and the cpp program doesn't validate this situation, therefore a `Segmentation Fault` occurs.

After using a valid font, all runs smoothly.